# MSBuild doesn't deploy and prints no error

Tags: msbuild, .net-core

I'm trying to publish my project using MSBuild. Here's the command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" D:\HamrahFarda\KhandeShow\KhandeShow.sln /t:UserService /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=DeployUserService /p:SolutionDir=D:\HamrahFarda\KhandeShow /property:PublishFolder=C:\Publish\KhandeShow\UserService
```

That full command can be broken into these parts:

I use MSBuild.exe that is installed with VS 2017 community edition for .NET Core.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
```

I have a solution, and I only want to build and publish a project inside it. Thus:

```
D:\HamrahFarda\KhandeShow\KhandeShow.sln /t:UserService
```

I want it to deploy the built project:

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true
```

I've created a publish profile beforehand:

```
/p:PublishProfile=DeployUserService
```

This is the publish profile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishDir>C:\Publish\KhandeShow\UserService</PublishDir>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And last but not least, I'm overriding some properties and providing new ones to be used inside `.csproj`:

```
/p:SolutionDir=D:\HamrahFarda\KhandeShow /property:PublishFolder=C:\Publish\KhandeShow\UserService
```

But without any error (with a bunch of warnings) it doesn't publish anything to the destination folder. I'm stuck. Can you help please, cause MSBuild is really not handy and friendly.

Comment: Learn how to enable MSBuild diagnostics logging and then analyze the logs.

Comment: @LexLi, based on [this reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx) I used `/fileLoggerParameters:LogFile=MyLog.log;Append;Verbosity=diagnostic;Encoding=UTF-8` and it produced 74 MBs of log file, almost a million lines. That's impractical and can't be used for debugging purposes. Even scanning a million lines is not OK, let alone trying to find what's the problem.

Comment: You can also us `/bl` and the [structured log viewer](https://github.com/KirillOsenkov/MSBuildStructuredLog) to analyse logs. But in most cases, this issue appears because the VS/Build tools used don't have the web and cross-platform development workloads installed. can you check in the visual studio installer (separate application) if your installation contains these? (select "Modify" in the installer)

Comment: @MartinUllrich, I looked there and cross-platform development is installed.

Comment: can you share your project file or the binlog (`/bl` switch) from your project? can you build & publish a new web project using the same technique?

Comment: @MartinUllrich, [msbuild.binlog](https://ufile.io/3bh3c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the log you posted I was able to determine the following:

The project you are trying to publish via a web publishing method is not a web project.

UserService.csproj is defined as

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

which is a "normal" sdk-style .NET project. If you want to perform a file system publish of these projects, use `dotnet publish` or its msbuld equivalent `msbuild /t:Publish` instead.

If the project really is a web project, you should change it to

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

To get web tooling and publishing support.

**Update**: also note that `PublishDir` in the publish profile is not the correct variable to set in the publish profile. Use `PublishUrl` instead so that the FileSystem publish method will copy the files to the right directory.

Comment: non of those actually made any difference. Still no output in the publish folder specified. I found out that it's [a known issue of MSBuild](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/1901).

Comment: I am aware of most the issues in this ticket (my name on GH is dasMulli). Most of them are configuration or environment errors. I'm happy to take a look into your issues again if you change to the web sdk and produce another binlog. Sadly, these issues are hard to diagnose since web publishing is mostly convention-based so there are no errors if the right things aren't in place.

Comment: Dear @martinullrich, I'm glad that you're here to help. Thank you so much. [Here's the new uploaded binlog file](https://ufile.io/rhmz6)

Comment: Good news, all targets are now imported. But your profile needs to set `PublishUrl` instead of `PublishDir`. Looks like it added created files in your project's root folder because `PublishUrl` resolved to an empty string

Comment: Damn, Martin Ullrich you're like a superhero knowing-it-all. How did you know that it published stuff to my root folder. God, I read that and I was like, what, he knows, how?

Comment: The binlog for the file filesystem publishing step contained a lines that showed copy from an intermediate publish step to a relative destination without the final publish path so I figured this is what's missing. and a look at the source code showed me that it normally would [insert `PublishUrl` in that step](https://github.com/aspnet/websdk/blob/4242b7c808ab0b87cb4e48ca79a44001e4e0f276/src/Publish/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Targets/netstandard1.0/PublishTargets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.FileSystem.targets#L44).

Comment: And a non-"rooted" path is always relative to the project file